# Blowfish encryption

Tags: blowfish, java

Есть задача: зашифровать текст таким образом, чтобы текст в зашифрованном виде имел вид alphanumeric (латинские буквы и цифры). Используя Blowfish.

Есть следующий код:

```
    String keyPhrase = "testKey";
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyPhrase.getBytes("UTF8"), "Blowfish");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF8"));
    System.out.println(new String(ciphertext, "UTF8"));
```

Зашифрованная строка в результате этого кода содержит неопределенные символы ("?" и квадраты).

Как можно получить строку в том виде, в котором мне нужно?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

преобразовать в Base64

Comment: Поддерживаю. Если взять [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/codec/), то нужно написать всего пару строчек:

      import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

и

      String based = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(ciphertext.getBytes()));

Comment: Учтите, только, что в состав алфавита base64 входят также '+' и '/'.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!
Использовал стандартные BASE64Decoder и BASE64Encoder.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать не трактовать массив байт как строку в UTF-8, а, например, каждый байт представить в 36-ричном виде и склеить их (с паддингом '0' для всех чисел меньших 'z').